# How to Disable multiple tab groups in Avalon Dock

Tags: c#, avalondock

how can we disable the option of New Horizontal / Vertical Tab Group in Avalon Dock Tab from XAML file. Could anyone possible help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Could Not think of any thing.

Comment: Could YOu please help me anyone !